# iPad Split View Development

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have recently begun app development for the iPad. I need to develop an app similar to the BBC news app - UI wise. I was looking into the UISplitViewController examples and tuts. It seems that the width of both the sub views cannot be changed. I would like to know bbc news app has accomplished this, also in portait mode the description view takes up the whole screen and there is single row of news articles on top, would like to know how this can be made possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to build your own split view.